# How to adjust the height of the bottom sheet

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

So I have created a bottom sheet and I was trying to adjust the height of this bottom sheet such that it takes 75% of the screen height. I imported Dimensions from react native and tried using this method

```
 Dimensions.get('screen').height;
```

```
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
const bottomSheetHeight = screenHeight * 0.75;
```

I calculated the height using the screenHeight constant and set it dynamically. The bottomSheetHeight variable calculates the height as 75% of the screen height. Then I passed it to the maxHeight prop of the bottomSheet as

```
<BottomSheet ref={bottomSheetRef} maxHeight={bottomSheetHeight} sliderMinHeight={0}>
```

I expected the bottomSheet to take up 75% of the screen height but nothing changed. Below is the complete code for your reference. Is there something wrong with the styleSheet or if I haven't used

```
Dimensions.get('screen').height;
```

method correctly.

Code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, FlatList, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet from 'react-native-simple-bottom-sheet';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';
//import CrossButton from '../../components/actionBar/CrossButton';

const BottomSheet1 = () => {
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef();
  const [expandedItem, setExpandedItem] = useState(null);
  const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
  const bottomSheetHeight = screenHeight * 0.75;

  const closeBottomSheet = () => {
    if (bottomSheetRef.current) {
      bottomSheetRef.current.togglePanel();
    }
  };

  const data = [
    { label: '2D Test' },
    { label: '2D Testing 2' },
    { label: '2D Testing 3' },
    { label: '2D Testing 1' },
    { label: '2D Testzaffar' },
    { label: '2D TestZaffar' },
  ];

  const expandedData = [
    { label: 'Dashboard' },
    { label: 'List of Subspaces' },
    { label: 'View Space Details' },
    { label: 'Create Subspace' },
  ];

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    const isExpanded = expandedItem === index;

    const handlePress = () => {
      LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
      setExpandedItem(isExpanded ? null : index);
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={handlePress}>
          <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>{item.label}</Text>
            <MaterialIcons
              name={isExpanded ? 'keyboard-arrow-up' : 'keyboard-arrow-down'}
              size={24}
              color="#555"
              style={styles.arrowIcon}
            />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {isExpanded && (
          <FlatList
            data={expandedData}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.rowContainer}>
                  <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.rowLabel}>{item.label}</Text>
                    <MaterialIcons
                      name="keyboard-arrow-right"
                      size={18}
                      color="#555"
                      style={styles.rowArrowIcon}
                    />
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                {item.label === 'List of Subspaces' && <View style={styles.separator} />}
              </>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.label}
            style={styles.expandedList}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BottomSheet ref={bottomSheetRef} maxHeight={bottomSheetHeight} sliderMinHeight={0}>
        <View style={styles.bottomSheet}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => closeBottomSheet()} style={styles.closeIcon}>
            <MaterialIcons name="close" size={24} color="#000000" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={[styles.title, { fontFamily: 'Montserrat' }]}>Truminds</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.create, { color: expandedItem !== null ? '#0F8D48' : '#4D4D4D' }]}>
              + Create Subspace
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.separator} />
          <FlatList
            style={styles.list}
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.label}
            maxHeight={250}
          />
        </View>
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: 0,
    paddingTop: 28,
    paddingBottom: 12,
  },
  itemContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginBottom: 17,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 800,
    color: '#4D4D4D',
  },
  create: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: 600,
  },
  bottomSheet: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    marginTop: -20,
  },
  separator: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  list: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  listItem: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingVertical: 10,
  },
  labelContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingBottom: 3,
    paddingTop: 3,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 600,
    color: '#4D4D4D',
  },
  arrowIcon: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    color: '#000000',
  },
  closeIcon: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
  rowContainer: {
    paddingHorizontal: 4,
    paddingVertical: 10,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  rowLabel: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#4D4D4D',
  },
  rowArrowIcon: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    color: '#000000',
  },
});

export default BottomSheet1;
```

Comment: You have to use the `sliderMaxHeight` prop instead of the `maxHeight` prop. For a list of all the available props, refer to the props-section in the [documentation](https://github.com/StefanoMartella/react-native-simple-bottom-sheet#props)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Yeah sure, I am new to react native. I'll have a look at this documentation